# How to debug parallel scons builts

Tags: scons

I have a rather complex SConstruct file and set up, so pasting it here is impractical.  When I run `scons -j 8` the build fails with some C++ errors.  However, when I run the same clean build with just `scons` (so, no parallel built) then the compile finishes fine. I think that I have some dependencies problem that only appear when the code is compiled in parallel. The build takes a long time so I would like to fix this problem.

How can I debug scons so that it tells me where the problem lies?

Comment: What are the errors you get? If it has to do with directory paths or files not existing, I had a similar error once and can help with a solution.

Comment: @Brady: Some times yes.  Some of our code depends on eachother and uses scons to work out what to compile in what order. Some of that order gets messed up when scons runs in parallel. At least, that's what I suspect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had similar problems in my build system at work. The first problem I encountered was very strange, as it seemed like SCons was completely messing up the directory it was supposed to be in. Upon consulting the SCons user's mailing list, I was told that you cant change directories with `os.system('cd ...')`, or similar while building in parallel. I wasnt doing anything like that, but upon further inspection found that the Python `shutil.make_archive()` function I was using in a custom builder was indeed changing directories. When I changed that, the parallel build worked much better. So, if you have any custom builders, etc make sure they are not changing the directory.

I still had problems though, similar to yours where the dependency system didnt seem to be working correctly while building in parallel. I later realized that it was my fault as the dependencies weren't as I originally expected. You can use the `scons --debug=tree` command-line option to help debugging the dependencies.

I originally thought that SCons had bugs in its parallel build system, but later found that its actually quite robust, and the errors I had in my build scripts made perfect sense that the parallel build would break.